# wordpress full site editing problem when extending core blocks

Tags: wordpress, react-props

Hi i am extending the heading block using the filter hooks functions. so i am using the "blocks.registerBlockType" to add additional attributes. i am using the "editor.BlockEdit" to have my inspactor controls and update the attributes values. and i use the "blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps" to save the added attributes on the front end.

and indeed all attributes pass to the front side. but, the issue is that while editing none of the changes are reflected in the full site editor. the attributes are changing but it does not displayed inside the full site editor.

for example: this is a function that change the margin top attribute:

```
  const updateMTDvalue = (newDTval) => {
  setAttributes({ marginTop: (newDTval === undefined ? '' : newDTval) });
}
```

and as i said the new values does pass to the save function and works on the front end. but in the full site editor....nothing.

so i thought maybe i should add styles in the edit function like so:

```
if (attributes.desktopTop && attributes.desktopTop != undefined && attributes.desktopTop != '') {

props.attributes.style = {
    ...props.attributes.style,
    'display': 'grid',
    '--this-is-custom-variable': '#444',
    marginTop: attributes.desktopTop + attributes.desktopUnit
};
 }
```

as you can see i also try to hard code display and even a css custom property, as well as the attribute values. none of it pass the the element.

but when i have tried this:

```
    props.attributes.style = {
    ...props.attributes.style,
    'display': 'grid',
    '--this-is-custom-variable': '#444',
    marginTop: attributes.desktopTop + attributes.desktopUnit,
    typography: {
        fontSize: '3rem'
    },
    spacing: {
        margin: {
            top: fullTopM
        }
    }
};
```

the spacing and typography does work on the element inside the full site editor.

any idea why? why the update function itself, that update the attribute, does not change the element in the editor? and how can i add the styles to the element in the editor?

NOTICE i am talking about the full site editor, not the posts and pages editor.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: no. hoped someone has finally came with an idea :)